The alternative method to get the stake account status since `getStakeActivation` is deprecated
The official documentation recommends using getStakeActivation to retrieve the stake account status:
https://solana.com/docs/clients/javascript-reference#stakeprogram
However, when I use `getStakeActivation, the comments indicate that it is deprecated:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/b03a237ae6365eef498044d583ff5d7803ad452b/packages/rpc-api/src/getStakeActivation.ts#L18
What is the recommended method to get the stake account status at the moment?

It's a bit more difficult, but you'll need to pull down the appropriate information (the stake account, stake history, and current epoch) and calculate it yourself. I've created a gist you can use to get the information with an RPC client at https://gist.github.com/joncinque/ccd5166a857d629f30b2c01cd010041d

Thanks for the answer! I found another easier solution by getAccountInfo RPC method.

Ok great! Note that getAccountInfo won't give detailed warmup / cooldown numbers for the stake account, but if you don't need that, it's definitely a better option

Finally, I use getAccountInfo to get StakeAccount.
The structure reference is like this:
https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/27eff8408b7223bb3c4ab70523f8a8dca3ca6645/account-decoder/src/parse_stake.rs#L42

You can find a client side replacement for getStakeActivation for Rust and Js here:
https://github.com/solana-developers/solana-rpc-get-stake-activation
It will probably soon be also also released as a seperate package.
